# How to stop arrival rate from source in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

My current fire evacuation simulation model begins when I push a button which triggers the fire alarm. I would like to stop pedestrians from arriving during the evacuation process.

Below is my flow chart:
[image]

For example I want to stop pedestrians from source pedOffice from arriving the building area after I push the Fire Alarm Button. Below is my properties settings:
[image]

I have tried using the code
`pedOffice.set_rate(0);`
But the pedestrians continue to arrive after the button has been pressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 options for this:

**Option 1** 
You need to first change the type of arrival to rate, otherwise set_rate has no effect:

```
pedOffice.set_arrivalType(pedOffice.RATE);
pedOffice.set_rate(0);
```

**Option 2**
You can change the maximum number of arrivals to the amount that has arrived:

```
pedOffice.set_maxArrivals(pedOffice.countPeds());
```